# Can I compile spec and body simultaneously in toad?

Tags: plsql, package, toad

I want to compile a package in toad. I have a package spec and a package body. Do I need to compare them separately or is there any way to compile both at one shot?

Thanks for the answers

Comment: The title of a question is *not* to put the first phrase of your question in. Instead, put the first phrase of your question in the question body, and provide a separate title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install first package spec

```
@xx.pks
```

After that package body

```
@xx.pkb
```

by pasting the files to  TOAD and executing **F5** (Execute as Script).
And compile optionally.

You can paste these two files to one Toad tab if you want it in one shot.

Answer (score 0):

Also we can make a single .sql file eith both specs and body in it and just press F5 to execute. For example

```
CREATE OR REPLACE package            <package name>
as
PROCEDURE xyz;
End ;
/


CREATE OR REPLACE package body       <package name>
as
PROCEDURE xyz
AS
BEGIN
NULL;
END;
END;
/
```